# How to find the parent class of VGG16 prediction?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, vgg-net, imagenet

I am using a keras based vgg model as an image classifier. From this webpage:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-pre-trained-vgg-model-classify-objects-photographs/

But I am interested to find out the parent category of a prediction. For example, if the model predicts a dog, I would like to know its parent category which is animal.
I do not know if there is a way to use the Imagenet tree for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageNet` uses `WordNet` to create the hierarchy of classes. You can access the object synset in the following way:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

nltk.download('wordnet')
dog = wordnet.synsets('dog')[0]
```

To access the parents of the `dog`, call:

```
dog.hypernyms()
```

It might return more than 1 result which is problematic.

What you can do now, is to check if any of this parents is an actual `ImageNet` class. To get the `wnid` of the symset, just call `dog.offset()`.

To reverse the process:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synset_from_pos_and_offset('n',2084071)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I check the imagenet class name using wnid?

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam updated the answer. Feel free to upvote the answer when it's helpful and mark as a solution if it solves your problem.

Comment: but how can I check if any of these parents is an actual ImageNet class? Based on your answer we can only get the parent category label in WordNet.

Comment: http://image-net.org/archive/words.txt contains mappings. This is what you might be looking for. Feel free to continue asking. I'll try to answer tomorrow morning CEST

Comment: I think, that my final answer would be to create a tree based on the http://image-net.org/archive/words.txt and then implement a traversal towards the root.

Comment: @ xenteros , thanks for your help. Any suggestions on how to build this tree?